# PHP getting max value from array

Tags: php

hi following are output of an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_category] => 68, 67
            [cost] => 99
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_category] => 70
            [cost] => 100
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_category] => 70
            [cost] => 10
        )

)
```

How is possible to use array to filter only max value? SO the output will only be

```
Array
(

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_category] => 70
            [cost] => 100
        )

)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: from where You are getting this array? is it an output of your sql query?

Answer (score 3):

Foreach is your friend:

```
$maxObj = null;

foreach ($arr as $key => $obj) {
  if ($maxObj == null || $obj->cost > $maxObj->cost) {
    $maxObj = $obj;
  }
}

var_dump( array($maxObj) );
```

---

General function:

```
function arrayMaxCallback($arr, $cb) {
  if (count($arr) == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  $max = null;
  foreach ($max as $key => $obj) {
    if ($max == null || $cb($max, $obj)) {
      $max = $obj;
    }
  }
  return $max;
}
```

Use case:

```
$maxCost = arrayMaxCallback($arr, function ($max, $new) {
  return $new->cost > $max->cost;
});

// if you still have to use PHP < 5.3
function cmpCost($max, $new) {
  return $new->cost > $max->cost;
}

$maxCost = arrayMaxCallback($arr, 'cmpCost');
```

Comment: Take note that anonymous functions were first introduced in PHP 5.3

Comment: @h2ooooooo I know. I've added a further example.

Comment: I know that you know - it was a note to OP before he downvotes you for "code that doesn't work" :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$max = -999;
$max_obj = NULL;

foreach($array as $obj) {
  if($obj->cost > $max) {
    $max = $obj->cost;
    $max_obj = $obj;
  }
}
```

`$max_obj` is now the object with the highest cost.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple solutions of the problem(i like the second one better):

```
function foreach_max($array) {
  $max = $array[0];

  foreach ($array as $row) {
    if ($row->cost > $max->cost) {
      $max = $row;
    }
  }

  return $max;
}

function reduce_max($array) {
  return array_reduce(array_slice($array, 1), function ($max, $row) {
    return $max->cost < $row->cost ? $row : $max;
  }, $array[0]);
}
```